# Replace space with "NULL" in awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to convert a text file into HTML using awk command in shell script. Since the text file is auto-generated from server it contains server reponses, there are some empty values in the file as shown below

```
A 00
B 00
C 
D 
E 00
```

I want to replace this empty value with string "NULL" or "No response". Please suggest how it can be done.
[image: Table gererated from script for the above data]

I have tried this

```
awk '{print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
if($i==" ")
   {   
       print "<td>$i</td>";
   }
.........{some lines of code}
}'
```

Current Output
[image]
Expected Output
[image]

Comment: Please provide input file as text, not image, also observe that when you use default field separator - that is one-or-more whitespace character - you will never get single space as field

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response 
The text data is as follows 
A 00
B 00
C 
D 
E 00

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. You need to use ternary operator to check if `i` variable is NULL then print string `NULL` else print its actual value itself.

```bash
awk '
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
       print "<td>"($i!=""?$i:"NULL") "</td>";
   }
.........{some lines of code}
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response 
This is not replacing the space or empty values with "NULL" String 
Please suggest if there is anything else i can do

Comment: @User_01, then I would request you to edit your question with samples of input and expected output and let me know then.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   {   
       print "<td>"$i"</td>";
   }
   NF < 2 {
       print "<td>NULL</td>";
   }
.........{some lines of code}
}'
```

Awk uses whitespace as field delimiters. Your data appears to have missing fields which you want replaced. This is one approach. If the number of fields is less than two, print a table cell with "NULL".